# Github - The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration

Tags: eclipse, github

I got this error when I pull this repo from github. - https://github.com/datomnurdin/worklight-mobile

Error message

```
The current branch is not configured for pull 
No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't told Git which remote branch to merge into your current branch. Let's assume you're on a branch called `feature` and you want to pull from `origin/feature`.

Running

```
git branch -u origin/feature feature
```

will set `origin/feature` as the "upstream branch" of your local `feature` branch.

In your `.git/config` you should now see something like this (note the `merge` line):

```
[branch "feature"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/feature
```

Now you should be able to `pull` from it automatically.